# close-others "true" not working in ui-accordion when content is transclude

Tags: angularjs, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I have implemented accordion in my application. but close-other = "true" seems not working.

I implemented a common compenent to use collapsible component in my application-

Component-

```
  var uiCollapsiblePanel = {
       transclude: {
       header: 'uiCollapsiblePanelHeader',
        body: 'uiCollapsiblePanelBody'
        },
       bindings: {
       isBlockExpanded: '<',
       triggerCollapse: '&'
       },
      templateUrl: './ui-collapsible-panel.html',
      controller: 'uiCollapsiblePanelController',
     controllerAs: 'ucpc'
      };

    angular
    .module('common')
      .component('uiCollapsiblePanel', uiCollapsiblePanel);
```

ui-collapsible-panel.html -

```
 <div class=" ui-collapsible-panel">
  <uib-accordion close-others="true">
  <div uib-accordion-group  is-open="$ctrl.isBlockExpanded">
   <uib-accordion-heading>
    <div ng-transclude="header">
    </div>
   </uib-accordion-heading>
   <div ng-transclude="body"></div>
  </div>
</uib-accordion>
</div>
```

Calling ui-coolapsible-component-

```
      <div class="app-custom-accordian">
       <ui-collapsible-panel is-block-expanded='false'>
        <ui-collapsible-panel-header>
           <request-header all-requests-data="mrtt.allRequestsData"> 
      </request-header>
      </ui-collapsible-panel-header>
       <ui-collapsible-panel-body>
        <request-body all-requests-data="mrtt.allRequestsData" class="request-body-container"></request-body>
    </ui-collapsible-panel-body>
  </ui-collapsible-panel>
</div>
<div class="app-custom-accordian">
  calling-ui-collapsible-component
</div>
   <div class="app-custom-accordian">
  calling-ui-collapsible-component
</div>
  <div class="app-custom-accordian">
  calling-ui-collapsible-component
 </div>
```

can someone help me to identify whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In this example you implemented single accordion. This function will work if you have multiple uib-accordion-group's. And opening of one will cause other to close.

By documentation (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/): close-others $ C (Default: true) - Control whether expanding an item will cause the other items to close."

Hope, it will help.

*If this is not the case, i suggest to expand example with more details*

(edited)

so as i understood correctly you are trying to do generic reusable accordion. For that you created 'ui-collapsible-panel.html'.

The root wrapper 'uib-accordion' needs multiple uib-accordion-group's.
In this example you are transcluding inside one group.

```
<div uib-accordion-group  is-open="$ctrl.isBlockExpanded">
  <uib-accordion-heading>
    <div ng-transclude="header"></div>
  </uib-accordion-heading>
  <div ng-transclude="body"></div>
</div>
```

Which means you wont able to use 'close-others'. 
For this to work, you either need some ng-repeat or transclude directly uib-accordion-group's. Basicaly this multiple transclude (for header and body) is not usefull, because all this data must be in same parent "uib-accordion". Example of direct transclude:

```
<ui-collapsible-panel>
  // preload some data (for example groups)
  <div uib-accordion-group is-open="$ctrl.isBlockExpanded" ng-repeat="group in $ctrl.groups">
     <uib-accordion-heading>
     // and use group data to for request-header and request-body
       <request-header all-requests-data="mrtt.allRequestsData"></request>
     <uib-accordion-heading>
     <request-body all-requests-data="mrtt.allRequestsData" class="request-body-container"></request-body>
  </div>
</ui-collapsible-panel>
```

Reference https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (orignal uib-bootstrap plunker example)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just edited by question to show my implementation. I have implemented a generic collapsible component where included my content using ng-transclude